# GTK Widgets changing with CSS

Tags: css, c, gtk

I can change the color of a button with CSS (background und color). But this don't work for dropdown button and textview. Do you have any suggestions?

```
"#Button {\n"
"background: #FF0000;\n"
"color: #00FF00;\n"
"}\n"
```

For a text field is `font-size` and `font-family` working, but not `background` or `color`.

And 2nd question. Is there any documention, where all the possibilities of changing is written? For which Widget can what be changed?

Comment: You checked out these [docs](https://docs.gtk.org)?

Comment: Yes. I'm working among other things also with this. But I couldn't find a solution there.

Comment: I guess you are looking for the [Overview of CSS in GTK](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-overview.html).

Comment: Thanks David, it's helps a bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of trial and error identifying the specific CSS nodes for the button widget, dropdown widget, and textview widget, I was able to get the background colors and text/foreground colors to output with the requested behavior.  First off, I took advantage of a new capability within GTK4 to override the element name for the widgets so that any custom CSS definitions are only applied to the appropriate widgets.  That property is called "css-name".  Here is an example for the button that was defined in a "ui" file.

```
<property name="css-name">CustomButton</property>
```

For the widgets I defined in a "ui" file for my test program, I assigned the widgets  the following "css-name" property:

- <property name="css-name">CustomButton</property>   (in lieu of "button")
- <property name="css-name">CustomDrop</property>     (in lieu of "dropdown)
- <property name="css-name">CustomText</property>     (in lieu of "textview")

Within my test program, I define and create my widgets from the "ui" file with a GtkBuilder along with a CSS provider.  The following code snippet illustrates the elements and children that were identified for the application of custom CSS definitions.

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, "CustomText, CustomButton, \
CustomDrop > button, CustomDrop > popover.menu > contents {background-color: #FF0000; color: #FFFFFF;}", -1);

gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display (display, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

Probably, the thing to point out is identifying all of the children of the widgets to properly associate CSS style directives.

FYI, I associated the CSS provider with the display context, but it should work with the widget level context as well.

With that, I was able to get all widgets to have a red background.  For my example, I made the text white in lieu of green.  Following is a sample illustration.

[image: Sample of multiple widgets with red background]

Hopefully, that will point you in the proper direction.